# Is tensorflow a package or a module?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to understand TensorFlow terminology. When I code `import tensorflow as tf`, I can call functions like `tf.constant`. This implies that `tensorflow` is a module.

When I look at the files in the installation directory, I see that `tensorflow/contrib/learn` has an **init**.py file, which means it's a package. A module can't contain a package, so that implies `tensorflow` is a package.

I'm sure this is obvious to many, but I can't decide whether `tensorflow` is a module or package. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html, TensorFlow qualifies as a package- a directory-organized set of modules to structure its namespace.  It’s *composed* of modules:

> A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements.

This doesn’t mean that you can’t (as you’ve observed) import a package.  And that package’s `__init__.py` can expose definitions from subpackages and modules at the package-level namespace.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The difference between modules and packages in python is how the source code is organized:

- Any file containing python code is a **module**
- Any directory containing a file called *__init__.py* is a **package**. In addition, a package directory may contain any number of python source files (i.e. **submodules** of the package) and any number of directories which are themselves packages (i.e. **subpackages**).

Both modules and packages can be imported, and once imported they behave roughly the same. So for example you can use the `.` operator to access the contents of a module (`module.thing`) or a package (`package.thing`).